# fopen and getting system file descriptor

Tags: php, file, fopen, file-descriptor

I want to get a system file descriptor of the returned resource when I open a file using open. I assume the descriptor is an INT value which is normally inside /dev/fd/

I know that I can read from the descriptor by doing something like:

```
fread("php://fd/$descriptor", $buflen);
```

But now I want to get the descriptor for a resource opened by PHP's `fopen`(). Is there a way?

Comment: `stat()` would not return any FD information. It details purely with the on-disk file metadata, none of which concerns who's holding an open handle on the file. That information's retrieved from the OS's filesystem handlers.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my post accordingly. But I hope there is a way to get the system file descriptor from a PHP fopen handle.

Comment: Any reason you need the info? Breaking through abstraction layers is rarely a good idea.

Comment: I am writing a basic file system using the fuse wrapper for PHP. It seems to need the file descriptor there rather than PHP's descriptor.

Answer (score 4):

This is a rather hacky way around it but it works!

```
function fd($realpath) {
  $dir = '/proc/self/fd/';
  if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
      while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
          $filename = $dir . $file;
          if (filetype($filename) == 'link' && realpath($filename) == $realpath) {
            closedir($dh);
            return $file;
          }
      }
      closedir($dh);
  }
  return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're writing a fuse wrapper, consider [not duplicating the effort of this PECL extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/fuse).  Of course, it also doesn't have any freaking documentation, so this is a stab in the dark at best.