# Converting a socket resource into a stream socket

Tags: php, sockets, stream

PHP has two different APIs for interacting with sockets. There is the low level socket API which basically wraps the C socket API. And there is the high level stream sockets API, which implements the PHP stream interface.

Unfortunately, the stream socket API does not support setting low level socket options. However, this is something that I have to do. Likewise, the socket API does not support using standard function calls like `fread`, `fwrite` and `fclose`, making it incompatible with the rest of my code.

PHP 5.4 introduced the [socket_import_stream](http://php.net/socket_import_stream) function. This allows you to take a stream socket and get the underlying socket resource. My plan was to use this to create the stream socket, get the socket, set some options on it, and then continue using the original stream socket.

The reason this did not work for me is that I need to set the options before binding. The only way to bind a stream socket is to use [stream_socket_server](http://php.net/stream_socket_server), which already performs the bind. That's why I could not use it.

I am now looking for the inverse of `socket_import_stream`, so that I can convert my socket resource into a stream socket. I have not been able to find such a function, but I'm hoping that some very smart people can help me. Or submit a patch to the PHP source that does it. Or give me hints on writing such a patch.

EDIT: I have some code that acts on a PHP stream to parse DNS packets from it. I want to re-use that code with a multicast-enabled socket. I cannot enable multicast on a stream socket, and I cannot use stream functions on a raw socket.

EDIT2: I want to use this stream with `stream_select`, so custom stream wrappers are not an option, unfortunately.

Comment: Comment from PHP source code: `hold a zval reference to the stream (holding a php_stream* directly could also be done, but this might be slightly better if in the future we want to provide a socket_export_stream)` https://bitbucket.org/php/php-src/src/0ef8b095ccda/ext/sockets/sockets.c#cl-2524 So I guess `socket_export_stream` is function you are looking for, unfortunately looks like it is not implemented yet.

Comment: You are only presenting the problems you encountered implementing a "solution" to an undescribed problem. Lay out the original problem also, maybe there are other ways.

Comment: @Tiberiu-IonuțStan I have added some more information about my problem.

Comment: @igorw Instead of importing/exporting the socket handle from the stream, what do you think about extending the socket stream context to take an options array? In my opinion that would result in a lot cleaner code.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [stream_wrapper_register](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-wrapper-register.php) function in combination with a class which implements the [streamWrapper](http://php.net/manual/en/class.streamwrapper.php) template to create a multicast socket stream. This will allow you to leverage all of the built in stream functions, though it is not as convenient as socket_export_stream.

Comment: This is the right solution. Since there's so much you can do with a socket, implementing the wrapper should be trivial.

Comment: This helps a bit, however there is one issue with this solution. Custom streams cannot be used with `stream_select`, because there is no way to extract the file descriptor. Adding this to the question now.

Comment: Can we use a direct access to the file descriptors like `php://fd/N` to determine the current one that is our?

Comment: @Alexander You [can get file descriptors for each stream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600811/fopen-and-getting-system-file-descriptor), you'll need to be knowledgeable of them as each stream is created, but that's possible with some work.

Comment: Custom streams can be used with the dark magic of [http://www.php.net/manual/en/streamwrapper.stream-cast.php] streamWrapper::stream_cast function

Comment: @Alexander Correct, if you store a reference to the socket inside your wrapper this should make using a wrapper a plausible solution.

Comment: Is it possible to get the fd of a socket?

Comment: Look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600811/fopen-and-getting-system-file-descriptor). It uses the stat command in the underlying operating system which returns a list of the active process's file descriptors. Included in this information is what type of resource is held by the descriptor, which shows 'socket...' if the fd points to a socket. You will have to do some parsing on the output from 'stat' to grab specific descriptors for your socket.

Comment: It doesn't seem very reliable (if I have many sockets I cannot distinguish them), and does not work on bsd.

Comment: You can identify sockets if you track the highest numbered fd during the creation of your stream. However I agree this isn't ideal. stream_cast should eliminate the need for using file descriptors at all.

Answer (score 5):

> The reason this did not work for me is that I need to set the options before binding. The only way to bind a stream socket is to use stream_socket_server, which already performs the bind. That's why I could not use it.

The 4th parameter of [`stream_socket_server()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-server.php) is `$flags`, which defaults to [`STREAM_SERVER_BIND | STREAM_SERVER_LISTEN`](http://php.net/manual/en/stream.constants.php), so do not ommit it, give `0` (or another flags).

After all setting is done, you can still manually bind (& listen) that socket using `socket_bind()` & `socket_listen()`.

I didn't tried, just an idea.

Comment: @Leigh Not true, note the `== 0` in the second line you linked.

Comment: @igorw You're right, for some reason I thought it was actually doing `& ~STREAM_XPORT_SERVER` to retrieve the original flags, and checking it against 0 which is what `STREAM_XPORT_CLIENT` is defined as. So indeed, a flags of 0 will skip the bind/listen portion.

Comment: This was a great idea, but unfortunately `socket_import_stream` tries to obtain the socket family, which does not exist when creating the server without flags. I get "Warning: socket_import_stream(): unable to obtain socket family [9]: Bad file descriptor".