# PHP get file descriptors

Tags: php, networking

I am looking for away to get the file descriptors used in fopen, stream_socket_server, socket_listen, and so on. I have spent a few hours tiring to find this and cant seem to. The reason for this is so I can pass that on to other processes to handle the work.

Edit:
I am making a simple http server in php, but pre-forking the php processes. The idea is that if the master processes accpets the connection and over a unix socket gives a different processes the fle descriptor then it can finish reading the data in and even processes and respond removing the bottle neck from the master processes. Currently the master processes has to read the data in send that over the unix socket the child processes and then writes back tot he unix socket and the master sends it back.

Comment: Can you provide more information about what you are trying to do?

Comment: @datasage edited the questions for more info

Comment: That makes sense, but I am not sure

Comment: @datasage what is werid is php has the interface for reading and writing file descriptors, http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php the issue is there is no way to get the fd of any file you have open with php or network connection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600811/fopen-and-getting-system-file-descriptor

Comment: @Bubba i was thinking about that, it works well with files but i am not sure how i would get it to work with a network connection, also if the same client has more then one connection then i wont know which one is the the one i should be working with.

Comment: if on unix*, check Josh Waihi's answer here
http://stackoverflow.com/a/7033247/1067003

Answer (score 0):

File descriptors are specific to a process, so you can not just pass them to another one and access them from there. If you fork a process, you have access to every file opened before the fork from both processes, but any file you open later on is only valid for the process that got the descriptor assigned. So even if you manage to obtain it, it won't solve your problem.